# How to use data from $resource in a query for another with Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-resource

I'm still learning Angular and am having some trouble accessing and using data across $resources.
I have two api calls with two sets of data: wagers and users.

url:/users/me returns current username and id as an object

/wagers returns all wagers as an array.
there is one field in wagers called userA, wagers?userA=(current user id) returns all the wagers whose userA=the current users id.

I am having trouble getting the (current user id) to dynamically pull in the current users id. My code is below:

```
//services
.factory('User', function($resource, $cookies){
    return $resource('users/me', {}, {
        query: {method:'GET', params:{}, isArray:false}
    })
})
.factory('Wager', function($resource, User){
    return $resource('wagers/', {}, {
        query: {method:'GET', params:{}, isArray:true}
    })
})

//controller
function WagerListCtrl($scope, $cookies, User, Wager){
    $scope.users = User.query
    $scope.wagers = Wager.query({"userA":user.id})
}
```

Comment: You might want to add parens on the query call like this: User.query()

Comment: Another thing is $resource is only a promise, so $scope.users most likely won't be available until after the the controller is done executing. You should call Wager inside of a success callback.

Comment: Can you clarify, how is "current user id" supposed to "dynamically pull in the current users id"?

Answer (score 3):

First off, you need to call query with parentheses, like: `User.query()`

Secondly, $resource only provides promises, so $scope.users most likely won't be available until after the controller is done executing. You should call Wager inside of a success callback.

```
User.query({}, function(data) {
  $scope.user = data;
  // assuming user has an id field
  $scope.wagers = Wager.query({"userA":$scope.user.id});
});
```